# How to specify an Arma(1,1)-fiGARCH(1,d,1) with rugarch package in R?

Tags: r

I have difficulties in understanding how to specify an  Arma(1,0)-fiGARCH(1,d,1) with rugarch package; I can't find a working example for this model on the web. In this way is correct? And the parameter "delta"estimated by ugarchfit indicates the "d" in the specification?

```
spec <-ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "fiGARCH", garchOrder = c(1, 1)), mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(1, 0)))
```

thank you all for the attention.